# Data Not displaying on Select2 with ajax

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I'm using jQuery select2 with ajax in codeigniter.

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<select id="country" name="country" style="width: 100%;"></select>
<span class='text-red'><?php echo form_error('country_name'); ?></span>
</div>
```

My select2 ajax code is:

```
jQuery('#country').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: '<?php echo site_url('countries/get_countries')?>',
                dataType: 'json',
                type : 'GET',
                data: function (param) 
                {
                    return {
                        countries : param.term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    var myResults = [];
                    jQuery.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        myResults.push({
                            id: item.id,
                            text: item.name
                        });
                    });
                    return {
                        results: myResults
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

returning JSON string is like:

```
[{"id":"14","name":"India"},{"id":"18","name":"USA"},{"id":"20","name":"jaipur"},{"id":"21","name":"shri lanka"}]
```

This code is not displaying anything.
What is the mistake in this code?

Comment: Still want an answer ? Probably not. Time goes so fast.  5 years already !

Answer (score 0):

try
changing `results: function (data) {`
to   `success: function (data) {`

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation here: https://select2.github.io/options.html#ajax, the key for processing the results is `processResults` and not `results`. Have you tried changing that? Also the documentation of `processResults` states:

> You can modify the results that are returned from the server, allowing you to make last-minute changes to the data, or find the correct part of the response to pass to Select2. Keep in mind that results should be passed as an **array of objects**. The object should contain an array of data objects as the `results` key.

Answer (score 0):

Array of Objects, make sure your object has the following properties:
 id (This is for the value of the  tag)
 text (This is for the displayed text in the  tag)
Use processResults instead of Results.

In your AJAX request inside your Select 2 Object, you will have to modify the processResults property of the Select 2 Object’s AJAX object. (That’s a mouthful).
In the processResults property, you will use an anonymous method and return the results.

Example:

```
$("#selectUpsells").select2({
  ajax: { 
   url:'admin/get-product-list',
   type: "post",
   dataType: 'json',
   delay: 250,
   data: function (params) {
    return {

      search_term: params.term
    };
   },
   processResults: function (data) { 
     return {
        results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
            return { id: obj.id, text: obj.product_name };
        })
     };
   },
   cache: true
  }
 });
```